# Custom module not showing up in module list

Tags: 7

I have been following this tutorial http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/module-development/how-to-create-module-1-basics-drupal-tutorial to create a custom module.

I created 2 files in my sites\all\modules\own\custom_module directory

1. irish_rail.info with the following:

name = Custom

description = Irish Rail API

core = 7.x

2. irish_rail.module with just an opening php tag

< ?php

I have been searching for the answer for a long time and nothing.

I cleared the cache. 
I checked if there is another .module file.

And the module still won't show up in my module list.

Is there anything else I can try. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change From < ?php to <?php in .module file.
Clear cache.

Comment: can you write full path where you have these files?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I do actually have it as <?php but for some reason when I was typing out the question it wouldn't display when I had it that way.

Comment: And the full path is C:\Users\Sara\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\own\custom

Comment: Check once more in "OTHER" section of module list and which version of drupal 7 you are using? There is no issue on code.

Comment: your path isn't right, add these files in `/sites/all/modules/custom/irish_rail` and clear cache

Comment: I am using Drupal 7,53. And I changed the path to C:\Users\Sara\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\custom\irish_rail and its still not showing up after clearing the cache

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

It turned out that when I was naming the files I was naming them custom.info and custom.module but wasn't giving them the proper extensions. They were still .txt extensions.

Something very small!

Thanks for the help though.